# State and prove an intermediate value theorem for functions mapping into the digital line.

Tags: general-topology

I'm sitting with the problem

> State and prove an intermediate value theorem for functions mapping into the digital line.

The digital line is defined as $\mathbb{Z}$ with the topology given by the basis elements $B(n)=\{n\},$ if $n$ odd, and $B(n)=\{n-1,n,n+1\}$ if $n$ even.

I really have no clue, where to start. I have tried just using the regular intermediate value theorem, but I cannot prove it in this case. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is your question about functions from the digital line to itself? Or do you mean functions from an arbitrary space into the digital line?

Comment: I mean from an arbitrary topological space to the digital line. I suppose it must be connected.

Comment: Is this problem from a particular textbook? Just wondering because I'm interested in digital spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**. Let $f : X \to \mathbb Z$ be a function from a space $X$ to the digital line. Suppose $f$ is continuous on a connected subspace $A$ of $X$. Let $a, b \in f(A)$. Then for any $c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $c$ is between $a$ and $b$, there exists an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = c$.

To prove the theorem, first show that any connected subspace of $\mathbb Z$ is a set of consecutive integers (use a proof by contradiction to do this). Since $A$ is connected and $f$ is continuous on $A$, $f(A)$ is also connected, and is therefore a set of consecutive integers. Hence, for any $c$ between $a$ and $b$, $c \in f(A)$, which means $c = f(x)$ for some $x \in A$.